# is there an $i$ of logarithms with negative bases and/or negative arguments?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

As you probably know, $\log_{a}(b)$ is undefined if $a<0$ and/or if $b<0$. Can a constant such as $i$ be used but for logarithms with negative bases and/or negative arguments? Can it even be defined like $i$ so that it is a unit such that every other number of this theoretical set of logarithms with negative bases and/or negative arguments can be expressed as a multiple of it? (Just like $i$ and the set of imaginary numbers).

Comment: Logarithms aren't defined for just $a<0$ and/or if $b<0$ but rather $\forall a,b,x$ which satisfy $a^x=b$ where $\log_a{(b)}=x$. So for imaginary numbers, $\log_{-1}i=\frac{1}{2}$ since $-1^{\frac{1}{2}}=i$.

Comment: @JC12: That is just one solution out of many. For instance, $-1^\frac52$ is also equal to $i$. So why isn't $\log_{-1}i$ equal to $\frac52$?

Comment: See https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/logarithm/Logarithm_of_Negative_Number.html which is also part of Sandejo's answer

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm can be extended to the complex numbers by defining the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) by $$\operatorname{Log} z = \ln |z| + i \operatorname{arg} z$$ where $\ln |z|$ is the real logarithm of the modulus of $z$ and $\operatorname{arg} z$ is the angle of $z$ in the complex plane for some [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts).

Comment: Why did you use “log” and “ln” in the same equation?  Are both of those supposed to be “ln”?

Comment: What base are you using in “log”?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw both are natural base. I use $\operatorname{Log}$ for the complex logarithm and $\operatorname{ln}$ for the real logarithm.

Comment: I would suggest using “ln” whenever using base $e$.  It eliminates confusion.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw this is the notation that was used in my complex variables class, and I use it because it clearly distinguishes between the real and complex logarithms.

Comment: The domain of arg z is $0\leq arg z \lt 2\pi$ right?  How does a branch cut come into play here?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw The domain of $\operatorname{arg}$ is $\mathbb C$. The range is $[\phi, 2\pi + \phi)$ for some branch cut $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

I will only consider here the case $a=e$ (aka the natural log). For any nonzero, complex base, you could change to the natural log with a complex argument.

The answer is, yes, you can define a log function for a general complex argument, but it gets a bit complicated. In the complex plane, the log function requires a branch cut to distinguish the exact branch. The reason for this is the exponential is actually periodic in the complex plane, so it has infinite candidates for an inverse.

I won't go into the details too much, but a complex log can be defined as follows.
$$ \ln(z) = \ln(re^{i\theta}) = \ln(r) + i\theta.$$
As $re^{i\theta} = re^{i\theta + 2\pi i}$, you have a level of freedom in choosing $\theta$. It is standard practice to take the principle branch as $-\pi < \theta < \pi$. If you wanted $\ln(-1)$, you might take the branch $0 < \theta < 2\pi$ to get $\ln(-1) = i\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Euler's formula opened to door to defining logarithms for arbitrary complex numbers.

If $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm, $i^2=-1$ and $H$ is the measure of a half-angle, then

$$e^{ix}=\cos(Hx/)+i \sin(Hx/)$$

We get Euler's Identity

$$e^{i}+1=0$$

from, this we derive

$$e^{i2z}=1$$

when $z$ is an integer.

and derive

$$ln(-1)=i+i2z=i(2z+1)$$

and

$$ln(i)=\frac{i(2z+1)}{2}$$

From here in out, we use the usual rules of logarithms to use arbitrary complex arguments and bases.